# Iframe Src from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have an Iframe in a view that i need to populate the src from my controller This is the part of the controller that it has to be called from.

```
 else
            {
                //TODO: add after mobile detection is added back in
                //if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
                //    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Mobile", new { Area = "" });
                //else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" });
            }
```

I know this is how youwould do it if it wasnt in MVC so how could i call my iframe from the controller?

```
ifr1.Attributes["src"] = "http://localhost:8000/index.php/login/?u=" + Session["username_s"] + "&p=" + Session["password_s"];

enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ViewData` or `ViewBag` for this purpose.

In your controller you should have the following:

```
else
{
    //TODO: add after mobile detection is added back in
    //if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    //    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Mobile", new { Area = "" });
    //else

    ViewBag.IframeUrl = "http://localhost:8000/index.php/login/?u=" + Session["username_s"] + "&p=" + Session["password_s"];

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" });
}
```

In you View you can use the following:

```
<iframe src="@(ViewBag.IframeUrl)"></iframe>
```

You can also use `ViewData` by replacing `ViewBag.IframeUrl` with `ViewData["IframeUrl"]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ViewBag` in the target action, passing the URL, for exemple:

1) Your target redirect action should look like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //Other code from the action here


  ViewBag.IFrameSrc = "http://localhost:8000/index.php/login/?u=" + Session["username_s"] + "&p=" + Session["password_s"];
  return View();
}
```

2) The `Index` View should look like:

```
<iframe src="@ViewBag.IFrameSrc">

</iframe>
```